# Java: If statement for the 'value' of an ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, netbeans, imageicon

I have a small program with a textfield, a label (for an image) and a button. When I press the button, it shows a standard image.

But, I want to change the picture if the input of the textfield equals a certain string, "car" for example.

When I use this, I get the error that I already defined 'foto' as a variable:

```
if ("car".equals(input)) {
    ImageIcon foto =  ImageIcon("C:......png");
```

This is the most important part of the code:

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String input = textfield.getText();
    ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon("C:.......png");
    label.setIcon(foto);
```

And this is the full code for this:

Main class:

```
package test4;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Test4 extends JFrame
{       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test5 frame = new test5();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

"Swing" class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test4;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class test5 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form test5
     */
    public test5() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        button = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.setText("Show");
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(121, 121, 121)
                        .addComponent(textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                        .addComponent(label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(147, 147, 147)
                        .addComponent(button)))
                .addContainerGap(124, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(button)
                .addContainerGap(63, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String input = textfield.getText();
        ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jordii\\Pictures\\music.png");
        label.setIcon(foto);

    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new test5().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton button;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textfield;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

So my question is: Is there another way to display a picture depending on the input of the textfield?

For example: If the input is 'car', display a picture of a car. If the input is 'house', display a picture of a house. Else, display a picture of a bike.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Do you know what a _declaration_ is?

Comment: `ImageIcon foto =  ImageIcon("C:......png");` Check your code to see if you don't use `foto`in the same method

Comment: I understand the error message, but my question is if there is another way to 'change' the picture, depending on the input in the textfield. So that, if the input is 'car', a picture of a car will appear. Or if the input is 'house', a picture of a house will appear. The label may be empty until a input is given, so that the picture appears after pressing the button. I know this way won't work because of the error, but I'm wondering if there is another way that works.

Answer (score 0):

Look, your code is not very pretty. Thus to maneuver in your code you need to *get* what it does.

All that aside, to answer your question:

If you get an error saying ... is already defined, then ... is already defined.
It's that simple. 
This example will show you how that works:

```
package test.project.main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        String a = "10";
    }
}
```

If you would try to run the above code, the compiler will warn you and will say that you already defined a variable with the name `a`. If you still proceed to run the code, a runtime exception will be thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Duplicate local variable a `at test.project.main.Main.main(Main.java:7)`

Now back to your `foto` example.

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String input = textfield.getText();

    ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon("C:.....png");
    if ("car".equals(input))
        ImageIcon foto = new ImageIcon("C:......png");

    label.setIcon(foto);
}
```

Here you can see that `foto` is already defined, the compiler will warn you about this. If you run the code and if the `if` statement is true (because the input is equal to 'car') then you will get a runtime exception, mind you: If you have a compiler error, you would probably get a **Unresolved compilation** error message at runtime.

You can fix it by avoiding duplicate names in the same method e.a. `foto` and `foto1` etc.
A better approach is to make one variable `foto`, and set it at runtime. This example below will explain how this works:

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String input = textfield.getText();

    ImageIcon foto;
    if ("car".equals(input))
        foto = new ImageIcon("C:......png");
    else if ("plane".equals(input))
        foto = new ImageIcon("C:......png");
    else if ("bike".equals(input))
        foto = new ImageIcon("C:......png");
    else
        foto = new ImageIcon("C:......png");

    label.setIcon(foto);
}
```